# Hiding UITabBar when showing UIViewController as modal

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I've got a UIViewController that has a modal window which I'd like to present over the entire interface, including the UITabBar.

My application hierarchy is this:

```
UITabBarController (A) ->
    UIViewController (B) ->
        UINavigationController (C) ->
            UIViewController (D) ->
                UIViewController (my modal view)
```

When I call `presentModalViewController` on D, the modal view is presented but underneath the UITabBar, or should I say, the UITabBar is still shown.

I've tried setting the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property to `YES` on the modal view controller, but to no avail.

Any ideas on why this isn't working for me?

Comment: I have never got that problem. All my modals are shown over the tab bar. I think it would be your hierarchy of controllers. Usually is UITabBarController->UINavigationController->UIViewController. I think you have to remove (B) if you don't have a good reason to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modal `ViewController` needs to be a direct child of the `TabBarController` in order to do what you want.

in ViewController "D", instead of :

```
[self presentModalViewController:...];
```

do:

```
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:...];
```

how you maintain a reference to the `TabBarController` is up to you.